# How to make one element in a list call an element in another list using python?

Tags: python

so say i have list1 and list2.

```
list1 = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n0,star,pound]

list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,star,pound]
```

How to i write a function that when an element of list one is called, the corresponding element in list2 is called?

this may have been answered in another post but I have not been able to find and / or understand how to do this.

---Edit---

John Coleman's comment answered my question, but to help others reading this in the future I will clarify a few things.

"call" might have been the wrong term to use, I'm definitely a novice at programming. Here is how i used the code with the help from this thread.

```
n1 = 5
n2 = 6
n3 = 13
n4 = 19
n5 = 26
n6 = 12
n7 = 16
n8 = 20
n9 = 12
n0 = 4
star = 17
pound = 27

inputs = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n0,star,pound]
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,star,pound]
shows = dict(zip(inputs,numbers))  
count = 1

def loop2():
for input in inputs:
    if GPIO.input(input) == False:
        print '%s' % shows[input]
```

Comment: What does it mean to "call" an element of the list? Your list doesn't seem to contain callables.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "element in a list is called"?  We usually thing of functions as things which can be called.  Is this a list of function names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.index()` to look up where an element of one of the two lists occurs, and then feed that index to the other list:

```
>>> list1 = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6','n7','n8','n9','n0','star','pound']
>>> list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'star', 'pound']
>>> list2[list1.index('n5')]
'5'
```

Alternatively, you can create a dictionary linking the two lists:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(list1,list2))
>>> d['n5']
'5'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that .index() returns ValueError when the item isn't found.  .find() will return -1 if the item isn't there.  If you use .index() you may need to use a try: except: statement whereas if you use find, you can test for >-1.

Comment: @JawguyChooser Good point -- OP would need to add some error handling to make this robust, but it seems to be the sort of thing that they are looking for (even though the wording was a bit vague).

Comment: You can also use `d = dict(zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy That is of course slightly shorter. I tend to find it fairly natural to think in terms of comprehensions, but why waste keystrokes? I'll edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not much can be answered if you do not clarify what do you mean by "corresponding element in list2 is called", you mean function call or something?

Anyway, no matter what the situation, you will need to define a relation between the two items in the lists you want. In the example above, my best guess is that `list1`'s `n1` -> `list2`'s `1`, or by index corresponding.

You can achieve this by define a dictionary, something like

```
relate_dict = {"n{}".format(k):k for k in list2}
```

so every `relate_dict[key1]`, with `key1` in `list1` will return corresponding in `list2`, i.e relate_dict['n1'] => '1'

In the case of index, just use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)